# Flag changes from start and end date

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have to write code in Hive UI (mix of sql & hive),

Below is ask:

[image]

```
Start date             End date           flag
10/10/19               defult date         0
11/10/19               10/20/19            1
11/21/19               10/20/19            1
11/21/19(2nd entry)   default date         0
```

if 1 entry in month then flag is 0, if multiple entries for same month then flag for latest date is 0 and others are 1.

This also includes timestamp, if two entries for same day then flag for latest will be 0.

Please let me know for more details. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must be storing the data as strings, because "default" is not a valid date value.  That is not a good format, but you can work with this.

You want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by substr(startdate, 1, 2), substr(startdate, 7, 2)
                                     order by startdate desc
                                    ) = 1
             then 0 else 1
        end) as flag
from t;
```

Of course, if the column is stored as a date/time value, then use the appropriate functions for extracting the month and year.

Comment: Thanks i will try it. Havent tested yet but found sample code as: Active = case when startdate= 
                     max(startdate) over (partition by month(startdate), year(startdate))
                then 1 else 0
           end

Comment: Gordon, I got into other work and back to run this query again. sorry for providing half info initially but in case of multiple entries in a day flag should chose latest entry.